# How to send parameter from React-Native to Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

WebView.js

```
// WebView.js

var PropTypes = require('ReactPropTypes')
var React = require('React')
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native'

var UIWebView = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    url: PropTypes.string
  },

  render () {
    return <RCTUIWebView {...this.props} />
  }
})

var RCTUIWebView = requireNativeComponent('RCTUIWebView', UIWebView)

module.exports = UIWebView
```

RCTUIWebViewManager.h

```
//  RCTWebViewManager.h

#ifndef RCTUIWebViewManager_h
#define RCTUIWebViewManager_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RCTViewManager.h"
#import <UIView+React.h>

@interface RCTUIWebViewManager : RCTViewManager

@end

#endif /* RCTViewManager_h */
```

RCTWebViewManager.m

```
//  RCTWebViewManager.m

#import "RCTUIWebViewManager.h"
#import "RCTUIWebView.h"

#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "UIView+React.h"

@implementation RCTUIWebViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(url, NSString);

- (UIView *)view
{

  RCTUIWebView *rctuiwebview = [[RCTUIWebView alloc] init];
  return [rctuiwebview getWebView];

}

@end
```

RCTUIWebView.h

```
// RCTUIWebView.h
#ifndef RCTUIWebView_h
#define RCTUIWebView_h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIView+React.h>

@class RCTUIWebView;

@interface RCTUIWebView : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *url;
//@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *uri;

- (UIWebView *) getWebView;

@end

#endif /* RCTUIWebView_h */
```

RCTUIWebView.m

```
// RCTUIWebView.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "RCTUIWebView.h"

#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

@implementation RCTUIWebView

NSString *URL = @"http://www.baidu.com";

- (void) setUrl:(NSString *)url {
  URL = url;
}

- (UIWebView *) getWebView {
  UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
  NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[ NSURL URLWithString: URL]];
  [webview loadRequest:request];
  return webview;
}

@end
```

I tried to render it with parameter 'url';

```
var BrowserView = require('./WebView')
<BrowserView
  style={{width: 400, height: 500}}
  url={this.state.event.landingPage}
/>
```

It shows

> "Exception thrown while executing UI block: - [UIWebView setUrl:]:
>   unrecognized selector set to instance 0x7fcf2de1e180"

in the stimulator and shows

> "[error][tid:main][RCTNavigator.m:514] Error
>   setting property 'url' of RCTUIWebView with tag #328: Error setting
>   property 'url' of RCTUIWebView with tag #333: Cannot adjust current
>   top of stack beyond available views"

in Xcode console.

I can't figure out why!

If I modified render part:

```
var BrowserView = require('./WebView')
<BrowserView
  style={{width: 400, height: 500}}
  //url={this.state.event.landingPage}
/>
```

It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Return instance of RCTUIWebView in RCTWebViewManager.m

```
//  RCTWebViewManager.m

#import "RCTUIWebViewManager.h"
#import "RCTUIWebView.h"

@implementation RCTUIWebViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(url, NSString);

- (UIView *)view
{

  RCTUIWebView *rctuiwebview = [[RCTUIWebView alloc] init];
  return rctuiwebview;

}

@end
```